# Set and get a HTML created in javascript to session local storage

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, html, jsf

I need that the below code persist to exist in page reload, Ok.

```
<br/>   
    <div style="font-size: 8pt;float: left;width:100%;margin-left: 15px;margin-top:5px;">
        some text here
    </div>
    <div style="width: 100%; height: 40px;">
        <div class="flechaDestinatario"/>
        <div class="textoDestinatario">
            more text here
        </div>
    </div>
```

I need to add dynamically in javascript some more elements, but you can consider it as example.
I put the elements of code above in a parent div, the div parent id is 'chatUsuario' and the javascript var name is 'mensagem', anyway,

```
var mensagem = document.getElementById('chatUsuario');

        if (mensagem != null) {
            $(mensagem)
                    .append(
                            '<br/>  <div style="font-size: 8pt;float: left;width:100%;margin-       left: 15px;margin-top:5px;">'
                                    + args.dataHora
                                    + '</div>'
                                    + '<div style="width: 100%; height: 40px;">'
                                    + '<div class="flechaDestinatario"/>'
                                    + '<div class="textoDestinatario">'

                                    + args.mensagemRetorno
                                    + '</div>'
                                    + '</div>');
        }
```

I try many things, but nothing with success, for example:

```
    localStorage.setItem('mensagensBackup',JSON.stringify(mensagem));


  $(window).load(function() {
        var mensagensBackup = localStorage.getItem('mensagensBackup');
    if(mensagensBackup!=null)
    {
        var retrievedObject =  JSON.parse(mensagensBackup);

        document.getElementById('chatUsuarioContainer').innerHTML=retrievedObject;
    }
});
```

I try too jStorage.js, without success again.

Both cases I have the same error: "converting circular structure to json"

I really try, but I can't solve this error

Any another solution? have a workaround solution? something that I can do?

Thanks so much ;)

PS: I using JSF 2.2 and Prime 5

Comment: What is the value of `mensagem`?

Comment: mensagem is a div, that contains the code <br/>   
    <div style="font-size: 8pt;float: left;width:100%;margin-left: 15px;margin-top:5px;">
        some text here
    </div>
    <div style="width: 100%; height: 40px;">
        <div class="flechaDestinatario"/>
        <div class="textoDestinatario">
            more text here
        </div>
    </div>

Comment: Yes, but what is the value of the variable? Show the code you used to assign the div into it.

Comment: Edited and includes code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't stringify a DOM element object directly because it contains a circular reference to itself (as the error message says). On the other hand you don't even want to do that because you're interested only in its HTML content anyway. So change the code to

```
localStorage.setItem( 'mensagensBackup', mensagem.innerHTML );
```

and later remove the `JSON.parse()` line which is unnecessary now.

(As a side note, most of the time it's more reasonable to save some sort of abstraction of the data instead of the entire HTML, but that's another discussion.)

Comment: function recuperaConversa()
 {
  var mensagensBackup = localStorage.getItem('mensagensBackup');
  
  if(mensagensBackup!=null)
  {
   var mensagem = document.getElementById('chatUsuario');

   if (mensagem != null) {
    $(mensagem).append(mensagensBackup);
   }
  }
 }

Answer (score 0):

you can store html sub tree in localStorage and restore in after reload

```
 localStorage.setItem('mensagensBackup',mensagem.innerHTML));


$(function() {
  var mensagensBackup = localStorage.getItem('mensagensBackup');
  if(mensagensBackup)
      document.getElementById('chatUsuarioContainer').innerHTML = mensagensBackup;
  }
});
```